# What is the difference between endpoints-framework:clientLibs and endpoints-framework:generateSrc?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I've just tested both of them and got the same results. Why?

My intent is to generate server stubs for Google Java Endpoints Framework from OpenAPI specification. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I must say I do not believe that our intention is not facilitate the creation of new projects using these tools. These tools were built for migrating old projects and are not a recommended path forward.

But to answer your question:

- `endpoints-framework:clientLibs` is an operation your run on your server side project (appengine). It just downloads a client library (zip) for you. You can process and use this downloaded library in another project to consume the endpoint.
- `endpoints-framework:generateSrc` is an operation you run on the endpoints consumer (or client). This is a helper that automatically includes the client library code in your project (it also downloads the client library), so you don't have to copy that code in yourself (or generate a library an import it in)